# Why does union consume more memory if the argument is a set?

Tags: python, memory-management, set

I'm puzzled by this behaviour of memory allocation of `set`s:

```
>>> set(range(1000)).__sizeof__()
32968
>>> set(range(1000)).union(range(1000)).__sizeof__()       # expected, set doesn't change
32968
>>> set(range(1000)).union(list(range(1000))).__sizeof__() #expected, set doesn't change
32968
>>> set(range(1000)).union(set(range(1000))).__sizeof__()  # not expected
65736
```

Why using a `set` as argument **doubles** the amount of memory used by the resulting `set`?
The result in both cases is identical to the original `set`:

```
>>> set(range(1000)) == set(range(1000)).union(range(1000)) == set(range(1000)).union(set(range(1000)))
True
```

Note that the same happens using a normal iterator:

```
>>> set(range(1000)).union(iter(list(range(1000)))).__sizeof__()
32968
```

And with the `update` method:

```
>>> a.update(range(1000))
>>> a.__sizeof__()
32968
>>> a.update(set(range(1000)))
>>> a.__sizeof__()
65736
```

At first I thought that it was because when `union` is called, it sees that the size of the other `set` is `1000` and thus decides to allocate enough memory to fit all the elements of both `set`s, but afterwards it uses only part of that memory, while in the iterator case it simply iterators over it and adds the elements one by one(which doesn't consume more memory since all the elements are already in the `set`).

But `range` is also a sequence, and so is the `list` in the first example.

```
>>> len(range(1000))
1000
>>> range(1000)[100]
100
```

So why this doesn't happen with `range` and `list` but only with `set`?
Is there any design decision behind this or is it a bug?

---

Tested on python 2.7.3 and python 3.2.3 on linux 64 bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2.7.3, [`set.union()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0e41c4466d58/Objects/setobject.c#l1178) delegates to a C function called [`set_update_internal()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0e41c4466d58/Objects/setobject.c#l931). The latter uses several different implementations depending on the Python type of its argument. This multiplicity of implementations is what explains the difference in behaviour between the tests you've conducted.

The implementation that's used when the argument is a `set` makes the following assumption documented in the code:

```
/* Do one big resize at the start, rather than
 * incrementally resizing as we insert new keys.  Expect
 * that there will be no (or few) overlapping keys.
 */
```

Clearly, the assumption of no (or few) overlapping keys is incorrect in your particular case. This is what results in the final `set` overallocating memory.

I am not sure I would call this a bug though. The implementer of `set` chose what to me looks like a reasonable tradeoff, and you've simply found yourself on the wrong side of that tradeoff.

The upside of the tradeoff is that in many cases the pre-allocation results in better performance:

```
In [20]: rhs = list(range(1000))

In [21]: %timeit set().union(rhs)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30 us per loop

In [22]: rhs = set(range(1000))

In [23]: %timeit set().union(rhs)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14 us per loop
```

Here, the `set` version is twice as fast, presumably because it doesn't repeatedly reallocate memory as it's adding elements from `rhs`.

If the overallocation is a deal-breaker, there's a number of ways to work around it, some of which you've already discovered.

Comment: In Python 2.7 built-in sets are [implemented in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0e41c4466d58/Objects/setobject.c), so your analysis looks at the wrong files.

Comment: @user4815162342: Great point, thanks. I've rewritten the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking too much, but I wonder why the same assumption wasn't considered for every kind of sequence. Obviously, with iterators you can't know the (posible)number of elements to insert, and you are forced to add them one by one, but in the case of a sequence you have exactly the same information as if it were a set. The only thing I can think of is that operations between sets probably are done much more frequently than sets and other types. Could this be the reasoning behind the multiple implementations?

Comment: @Bakuriu: I think only the original implementor can answer that with any degree of confidence.