# Memory usage: creating one big set vs merging many small sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, set

I used the [`%memit`](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html) magic function to measure memory usage:

```
In [1]: %memit n = pow(10, 7); range(n)
peak memory: 568 MiB, increment: 272 MiB

In [2]: %memit n = pow(10, 7); set(xrange(n))
peak memory: 824 MiB, increment: 447 MiB
```

OK so there seems to be an intermediate step where `xrange(n)` is instantiated into a full list. But what if I cut my list into 10 sublists, and union them one by one? This would be more memory efficient, right?

```
In [3]: %memit n = pow(10, 7); reduce(set.union, (set(xrange(p, n, 10)) for p in range(10)))
peak memory: 1260 MiB, increment: 897 MiB
```

Well, that didn't go as expected. Why does the `reduce` approach consume more memory than `set(xrange(n))`?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198042/why-does-union-consume-more-memory-if-the-argument-is-a-set   Note that `set.union` will use **more** memory if the argument is a set, because it assumes that there will be few common elements and thus it will allocate double the memory needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of misconceptions to be cleared. First of all, a `xrange` is *not* turned into a list before it is made into a `set` in `set(xrange(n))`!

The *peak memory* for the `reduce` approach comes from the fact that `set.union` returns a *new* value that is an union of the 2 result sets. And [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) internally stores an extra value, the `accum_value`. So on the last iteration of that `for` loop:

```
accum_value = function(accum_value, x)
```

The `accum_value` that goes into the function contains 90 % of 10⁷ elements, `x` contains 10 % of 10⁷ elements, but the return value will need space for all 10⁷ elements. Space for all these need to be reserved simultaneously. Only after the `function` has returned is the memory for the old `accum_value` and `x` released.

---

However this is not the end yet. The peak memory does tell how much memory was needed *in* the process, but not how much is in use *after* the operation completed if the set was still in existence.

Thus a different benchmark is needed:

```
In [1]: %memit n = pow(10, 7); result = set(xrange(n));
peak memory: 522.22 MiB, increment: 498.93 MiB
In [2]: %memit 42
peak memory: 513.83 MiB, increment: 0.12 MiB
In [3]: import sys
In [4]: sys.getsizeof(result)
Out[4]: 268435688
```

and

```
In [1]: %memit n = pow(10, 7); result = reduce(set.union, (set(xrange(p, n, 10)) for p in range(10)));
peak memory: 1063.20 MiB, increment: 1039.71 MiB
In [2]: %memit 42
peak memory: 779.77 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
In [3]: import sys    
In [4]: sys.getsizeof(result)
Out[4]: 536871144
In [5]: 536871144.0 / 268435688
Out[5]: 1.9999991357333977
```

So the memory usage for the `reduce` *drops* to 778 MiB after the execution; however it is still more than for the simpler set-constructing case. And as you can see, the `set(xrange(n))` does not need much of internal memory, as the memory usage drops by mere 9 MiB after the set has been constructed.

Most notably not only is the `reduce` approach slower; the **resulting set also consumes twice as much memory**. This is because a set is backed by a hashtable, and it is grown into larger whenever it is deemed that it has too many collisions. You've met pathological behaviour where the set of same values result in one taking twice as much memory as the other.

Answer (score 4):

[Per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), `reduce` is roughly equivalent to:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        try:
            initializer = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise TypeError('reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value')
    accum_value = initializer
    for x in it:
        accum_value = function(accum_value, x)
    return accum_value
```

Iterating over the `iterable`, `(set(xrange(p, n, 10)) for p in range(10))`,
requires about 447 MiB.
You might think that since this iterable is a generator expression you'll save memory, but integers are [saved in an internal free list](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm):

> “For speed”, Python maintains an internal free list for integer objects. Unfortunately, that free list is both immortal and unbounded in size.

So once each set has been instantiated, most of the memory it consumes is never freed.

The returned value `accum_value` also requires about 447 MiB. Together, the call to `reduce` thus requires roughly 447+447 = 894 MiB.